# Change flock (util-linux) source so that locks are closed on exec()

Tags: locking, flock

Currently flock works as follows:

```
% exec {MY}<test.txt
% ~/github/myflock/flock -E 101 -nx "${MY}" ; echo $?
0
% exec zsh
% exec {MY}<test.txt
% ~/github/myflock/flock -E 101 -nx "${MY}" ; echo $?
101
```

I want the second lock to succeed. So exec should cause the lock to close. Flock (util-linux) source:

```
...
switch (opt) {
case 's':
        type = LOCK_SH;
        break;
case 'e':
case 'x':
        type = LOCK_EX;
        break;
case 'u':
        type = LOCK_UN;
        break;
...
while (flock(fd, type | block)) {
```

Is there something that can be passed to `flock()` to make locks close on exec?

Comment: It seems incredibly wrongheaded to modify the well-known semantics of a central utility of your system in order to support a single script.  You have no way of knowing what other programs depend on its standard behavior, such that they may break if you apply such a change.  And worse: in this particular case, such breakage could lead to silent misbehavior and system corruption, because it could result in scripts not holding locks that they think they do hold, and performing actions that are unsafe under those circumstances.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: you could just assume I have a reason? It is: obtain the same behavior as of **zsystem flock**.

Comment: if your intention is to replace the system's `flock`, then any reason you could possibly have is a ***bad*** reason.  However, I have written answer that address the possibility that you want a separate, independent variant of `flock`, rather than to replace the system `flock`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: there's "z" before "system". Zsh has built-in flock support.

Comment: No amount of "z"s alters the fact that changing the semantics of a program on which other programs rely is a bad idea.  Changing the semantics of `zsh`'s built-in `flock` command would be less impactful than changing the semantics of the `flock`(1) utility would be, but it's still a bad idea.  Again, however, providing a *different* locking program (or a different shell) that has the locking characteristics you want is a reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event that you want to create a local variant of the `flock` utility, rather than to replace the system's `flock`, this is what you're dealing with:

On modern Linux, the `flock`(1) program is a wrapper around the `flock`(2) system call (older Linux has a `flock`(3) library function instead, which has different semantics).  The documentation for `flock`(2) explicitly and unequivocally says:

> Locks created by `flock`() are preserved across an `execve`(2).

There is no provision for `flock` locks to be closed on exec.  However, it also says:

> Locks  created  by  `flock`()  are associated with an open file table entry.  This means that duplicate file descriptors (created by, for example, `fork`(2) or `dup`(2)) refer to the same lock, and  this  lock may be modified or released using any of these descriptors.  Furthermore, the lock is released either by an explicit `LOCK_UN` operation on any of these duplicate descriptors, or when all such  descriptors have been closed.

You therefore have the alternative of using `fcntl()` to mark the file descriptor to be closed on exec.  When the FD is closed (on exec), the `flock` lock will be removed, too, provided that there are no other handles on the same open file description.  Obviously, however, the FD is closed as part of this approach, which may be an undesirable result.  Also, it is ineffective at releasing the lock if other handles on the same open file description survive the exec (which could be viewed as a feature).

Comment: Should fcntl() be called on descriptor used for flock()? After calling flock()?

Comment: The FD can be set close-on-exec either before or after the `flock`; it doesn't matter.  The release of the lock is a consequence of the open file description being closed, which setting the FD to be closed on exec causes to happen when you want, subject to the provisos already given.  `fcntl`() operations do not interact directly with `flock` locks.